# How to get pixel shaders version from .NET?

Tags: .net, wpf, directx, shader

I am writing a WPF application and need to show info about video card installed in the system. I've faced a problem that I can't get pixel version supported by current video card. How can I do this using .NET? (importing of external code, may be DirectX libs, is also a suitable solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF itself only offers basic information about the capabilities of the system via [the RenderCapability.Tier property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rendercapability.tier.aspx). [The tiers are described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196.aspx) in detail, but as long as you're at tier 2 you can use pixel shaders. However, tier 2 only really represents that DX9 or higher is available, so you should avoid using any pixel shader functionality beyond that. Maybe in WPF4 they've added another tier or more details, but I don't have my .NET 4 VM handy at the moment to check.

Beyond that, you could probalby use [Managed DirectX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_DirectX), which is now [the XNA Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203940.aspx), to get at lower level information.